light availability under bifacial solar modules
My research topic deals with light availability under bifacial solar modules and their influence on the formation and development of grassland biotopes of value level III in ground-mounted photovoltaic systems. In my thesis, simulation calculations on light availability under the modules, irradiation measurements in a PV park and the evaluation of these results with regard to the light requirements of possible indicator plants of a grassland biotope of value level III are planned. Now I am considering whether the simulation can be carried out with bifacial_radience. I would like to simulate the real bifacial fixed PV park or a representative part of the park. As I understand bifacial_radience, the sensors are under the module. Is it possible to simulate the sensors on the ground, because I am interested in the irradiance under the modules (on the ground) and between the row spacing to estimate the light availability for the plants. Thematically, there are parallels to Agri-PV, especially with regard to the testing of light intensity, shading, light homogeneity and edge effects specified in DIN SPEC 91434:2021-05, which is also not defined in more detail. Is my project possible with bifacial _radience? I don't have that much programming experience yet and am trying to learn the programme through the tutorials. Cheers, Tanja

This doesn't sound like a programming question.
